# 1 Hour 10 Minute Connection in New Istanbul Airport

Tags: short-connections, ist

We are flying DUB-TLV on TK, and have only just over an hour to connect in Istanbul. I wouldn’t be worried typically, but the Dublin flight has been late around 75% of the time recently, which makes me concerned.

Does Istanbul Airport make EU arriving flights go through transit security?

This airport is huge, and does not have any sort of internal transport that I am aware of.

There is a flight leaving an hour later, so if the inbound flight is delayed, I will probably just not bother running through the arrival corridors and let them bump me. 1 hour and 10 minutes is the MCT, so any delays will be on them AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say for sure but EU flights are normally not subject to security:

> Arrivals from EU, USA or Canada continuing to other international destinations are not generally subject to transfer security. All other international-international transfer passengers should clear transfer security.

([Source](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/turkish-airlines-miles-smiles/1964210-transferring-transit-istanbul-ist-airport-3.html))

If the plane is late, it will be the airlines fault that you have missed the connection.